# How do I reformat file in linux using AWK, Print

Tags: awk

**I have a input file like this.**

> ```
> axoradev05.hs.pru.com /dev/fslv20   1502.00 1174.80  327.20 79% /ora01/STAGE82A 
> axoradev05.hs.pru.com /dev/fslv21   1820.00 1438.35  381.65 80% /ora01/STAGE52A
> axoradev05.hs.pru.com /dev/fslv22    750.00  494.48  255.52 66% /ora01/STAGE62A
> axoradev05.hs.pru.com /dev/fslv23   1500.00 1049.42  450.58 70% /ora01/STAGE72A 
> axoradev06.production.local /dev/fslv17 642.00  554.23  87.77   87%  /ora01/MART54A 
> axoradev10.production.local
> axoradev11.production.local /dev/fslv08  30.00    7.39  22.61   25%  /ora01/BOARD01A 
> axoradev13.production.local
> axoramis01a.hs.pru.com /dev/ora01_lv58 1648.00  1413.70  234.30   86% /ora01/BUOMI01P 
> axoramis01a.hs.pru.com /dev/ora01_lv44 1345.00  1104.90  240.10   83% /ora01/CSREC01P 
> axoramis01a.hs.pru.com /dev/ora01_lv14  150.00    13.75  136.25   10% /ora01/INRP102P
> ```

I want it to then look like this.

> ```
>                axoradev05
> /dev/fslv20     1502.00   1174.80    327.20      79% /ora01/STAGE82A
> /dev/fslv21     1820.00   1438.35    381.65      80% /ora01/STAGE52A
> /dev/fslv22      750.00    494.48    255.52      66% /ora01/STAGE62A
> /dev/fslv23     1500.00   1049.42    450.58      70% /ora01/STAGE72A
>                    axoradev06
> /dev/fslv17      642.00    554.23     87.77      87% /ora01/MART54A
>                    axoradev10
>                    axoradev11
> /dev/fslv08       30.00      7.39     22.61      25% /ora01/BOARD01A
>                    axoradev13
>                    axoramis01
> /dev/ora01_lv58   1648.00   1413.70    234.30      86% /ora01/BUOMI01P
> /dev/ora01_lv44   1345.00   1104.90    240.10      83% /ora01/CSREC01P
> /dev/ora01_lv14    150.00     13.75    136.25      10% /ora01/INRP102P
> ```

```
i.e remove column 1 but use first 10 characters as a heading using awk,print,printf
```

**This is the script that creates the file and the what I am currently doing**

```
# COLLECT THE DATA
##################
/opt/local/sbin/pcmdrun -o aix "df -Pg" > /tmp/bifsize1 |
# FORMAT THE DATA
#################
awk 'NF>1{ printf "%18s %8s %6s %8s %8s \n", $7, $3, $6, $4, $5 }' /tmp/bifsize1 >> 
/tmp/bifsize.`date +'%Y%m%d'`.txt
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your attempt at solving your current problem yourself (as opposed to the script that generated the input file for your current problem) so we can help you. Also, if you don't want that current input format then show the output of `pcmdrun` so we can help you write a script that works directly on that rather than creating an intermediate file you don't want/need.

Comment: The pcmdrun is inhouse script that is used to run a command (in this case our AIX estate)

Comment: it is running the df command to get filesystem statistics and creating the input file I have shown above

Comment: at the moment we are taking that file and running the awk statement above

Comment: in this awk command we are not selecting column 1 (which contains the server name) as that would then show on every line.

Comment: Yes, that was clear from your question. Please re-read my comment and let me know if it's not clear what I'm recommending you do to try to get help.

Comment: In particular - you currently have `pcmdrun | awk > temp` and you're asking for help to do `awk temp > final` but why not just do `pcmdrun | awk > final` and not create the intermediate file instead? We can't help you do that, though, without knowing what the output of `pcmdrun` looks like.

Comment: so we want a solution that uses the col 1 (server name) as a heading. I can't show my attempt at solving my problem as I dont have one, which is why I am asking the question on how it can be done. At present the awk command just lists the filesystems and not the server they are from.                                                                       FILESYSTEM           TOT_GB    %USED   USED_GB   FREE_GB
________________     _____      ____    ______    ______
    /ora01/OCDB20T   540.00    52%   276.03   263.97
    /ora01/MART20A  1013.00    79%   795.06   217.94

Comment: output of pcmdrun                                                                          
axoradev02.hs.pru.com /dev/fslv09     1200.00    979.46    220.54      82% /ora01/STAGE10A
axoradev02.hs.pru.com /dev/fslv10      750.00    520.53    229.47      70% /ora01/STAGE12A
axoradev04.hs.pru.com
axoradev05.hs.pru.com /dev/dbs_lv01    240.00    132.62    107.38      56% /ora01/OCDBS60A
axoradev05.hs.pru.com /dev/dbs_lv06    900.00    606.92    293.08      68% /ora01/MART71A

Comment: output of awk                                                                                                                                                                  FILESYSTEM           TOT_GB    %USED   USED_GB   FREE_GB
________________     _____      ____    ______    ______
    /ora01/OCDB20T   540.00    52%   276.03   263.97
    /ora01/MART20A  1013.00    79%   795.06   217.94
    /ora01/OCDB10A   400.00    65%   259.95   140.05
   Columns reordered and not showing servername, but would like the servername as a heading as shown in original question

Comment: Don't add information in comments where it could be missed and can't be formatted, [edit] your question to contain all relevant information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do what you asked for given your intermediate file in your question as input:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ server = substr($0,1,10) }
server != prev {
    print "\t" server
    prev = server
}
sub(/[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/,"")
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
        axoradev05
/dev/fslv20   1502.00 1174.80  327.20 79% /ora01/STAGE82A
/dev/fslv21   1820.00 1438.35  381.65 80% /ora01/STAGE52A
/dev/fslv22    750.00  494.48  255.52 66% /ora01/STAGE62A
/dev/fslv23   1500.00 1049.42  450.58 70% /ora01/STAGE72A
        axoradev06
/dev/fslv17 642.00  554.23  87.77   87%  /ora01/MART54A
        axoradev10
        axoradev11
/dev/fslv08  30.00    7.39  22.61   25%  /ora01/BOARD01A
        axoradev13
        axoramis01
/dev/ora01_lv58 1648.00  1413.70  234.30   86% /ora01/BUOMI01P
/dev/ora01_lv44 1345.00  1104.90  240.10   83% /ora01/CSREC01P
/dev/ora01_lv14  150.00    13.75  136.25   10% /ora01/INRP102P
```

Comment: Thanks Ed, this solution has worked as I wanted.